# How do you transfer ownership of an element of boost::ptr_vector?

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

struct A {
    ~A() { cout << "deleted " << (void*)this << endl; }
};

int main() {
    ptr_vector<A>   v;
    v.push_back(new A);
    A   *temp = &v.front();
    v.release(v.begin());
    delete temp;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

> ```
> deleted 0x300300
> deleted 0x300300
> c(6832) malloc: *** error for object 0x300300: double free
> ```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ptr_vector<A>::release` returns a `ptr_vector<A>::auto_type`, which is a kind of light-weight smart pointer in that when an `auto_type` item goes out of scope, the thing it points to is automatically deleted. To recover a raw pointer to the thing, and keep it from being deleted by the `auto_ptr` that's holding it, you need to call `release` on that too:

```
int main() {
    ptr_vector<A> v;
    v.push_back(new A);
    A *temp=v.release(v.begin()).release();
    delete temp;
    return 0;
}
```

The first `release` tells the `ptr_vector` to give it up; the second tells the `auto_ptr` to give it up too.