# How to remove pointer from boost::ptr_vector without object being deleted?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

How to **exclude** pointer from boost::ptr_vector without his deletion? =)

Comment: If you can use C++0x, I'd recommend `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` over `boost::ptr_vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ptr_vector<A> v;
v.push_back(new A);
A *temp=v.release(v.begin()).release();
```

At this point you own the object exclusively through `temp`. If you don't need it, use this instead:

```
v.release(v.begin());
```

[code credit: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871267/how-do-you-transfer-ownership-of-an-element-of-boostptr-vector)]